# handling images in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array with image source. I need to show this images in ng-repeat. I am not able to fetch need assistance.

```
var images = ["http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":171}}}",
"http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":252}}}",
"http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":97}}}",
 "http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":411}}}"]
```

html :

```
<div ng-repeat = "image in images">
 {{image}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the proper JSON, kindly make it in proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `<img ng-src="{{image}}" />` and also wrap you image urls with single quotes(because there are double quotes in your URL).

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.images = ['http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":171}}}',
'http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":252}}}',
'http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":97}}}',
 'http://35.154/media?request={"request":{"service":{"servicetype":"6","functiontype":"1013","session_id":966},"data":{"mediaids":411}}}'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Its really useful.